# Varied amount of input data; Needing advice

Tags: python

Statistics are often calculated with varying amounts of input data. Write a program that takes any number of integers as input, and outputs the average and max.

For example, if the input is: `15 20 0 5`

It should output: `10 20`

```
input_number = input()
split_number = input_number.split()

sum = 0
max = -1

for n in split_number:
    sum = sum + int(n)

average_value = sum/len(split_number)
if (int(n) > max):
    max = int(n)

print(int(average_value), max)
```

I tried this, however, the program outputs `15 15` instead of `10 20`.

Comment: unless it's part of the exercise, you can do this more easily with the builtin `sum()` and `max()` functions!

Comment: Unrelated but relevant: python convention for names of variables that collide with built-in objects is to append a `_` after the name. I.e: `sum_` instead of `sum`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. The shown code correctly give 10 for the first number, and 5 for the second because the max is only computed from the last number. I suspect an indentation problem somewhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking at the python builtin functions: [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum), [max](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max), and [statistics.mean](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean).

In order to do this, you first need a list of `int`s, not `str`s. You can use a simple list comprehension to get that done like so:

```py
numbers = [int(number) for number in input().split()]
```

After you have your list of numbers, in order to get the maximum number, you can use `max(numbers)`. In order to get the mean average, you can use `mean(numbers)` (note: you must have imported mean from statistics before to use this). Finally, to get the sum of the numbers, just use `sum(numbers)`.

In order to get your desired output, this is what I would write:

```py
from statistics import mean
numbers = [int(number) for number in input().split()]

average = mean(numbers)
largest_number = max(numbers)

print(average, largest_number)
```

If, instead you do not want to import statistics, you can just use `sum(numbers)` instead (note: as you are using division this will always return a `float` whereas `mean()` might not):

```py
numbers = [int(number) for number in input().split()]

average = sum(numbers) / len(numbers)
largest_number = max(numbers)

print(average, largest_number)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Indenting is crucial here

You need the comparison with `max` to be done for *each* number, not just at the end.

A few extra tips:

- Don't overwrite the names `sum` and `max` which are built-in functions. The easiest way to avoid this is to use a longer name which doesn't collide with a built-in name, e.g. `total` and `maximum`.
- Avoid repeatedly `int`ing the string `n`. Instead, get it into a number once-and-for-all. Since you *only* need the numerical part of the input, get the input converted into a list of numbers immediately.
- A handy mnemonic technique is to use a singular noun like "number" for one number, and a plural noun like "numbers" for a list of numbers. That way all your `for` loops will have a stereotyped layout: `for thing in things:`
- Avoid naming a variable `input_number` if it is actually a *string*, and it contains *multiple* numbers (expressed as strings). A few years later when you read the program, you might wrongly believe that `input_number` is a number, or if you remember that it is a string, you might think it is a string form of a *single* number.

```
text = input()
numbers = [int(number) for number in text.split()]

total = 0
maximum = -1

for number in numbers:
    total = total + number
    if (number > maximum):
        maximum = number

average_value = total/len(numbers)

print((average_value), maximum)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few points you have to consider.

1. You should not use variable names like `max` or `sum` as these are built in functions. I have replaced them with `max_num` and `sum_num` respectively.
2. You have to put the `if` statement inside the `for` loop.
3. You should not cast `average_value` to an integer as it will reduce precision.

Modified code:

```
input_number = input()
split_number = input_number.split()

sum_num = 0
max_num = -1

for n in split_number:
    sum_num += int(n)

    if int(n) > max_num:
        max_num = int(n)

average_value = sum_num/len(split_number)

print(average_value, max_num)
```